# How to place the elements of a global list into a variable?

Tags: stata

For instance, I know that I can use a global list as column names for a defined matrix, e.g.

```
global letter = "a b c d e f g h"
matrix colnames mymatrx = $letter
```

..However, I want to create a Stata variable that has the elements of my global macro within a variable, something like this:

```
gen myvar = $letter (Note: this doesn't work)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear exactly what you want, but all of these three interpretations are legal:

```
clear 
set obs 8 
global letter "a b c d e f g h" 

gen letter1 = "$letter" 
gen letter2 = "$letter" in 1 
gen letter3 = word("$letter", _n) 

list, sep(0) 

     +---------------------------------------------+
     |         letter1           letter2   letter3 |
     |---------------------------------------------|
  1. | a b c d e f g h   a b c d e f g h         a |
  2. | a b c d e f g h                           b |
  3. | a b c d e f g h                           c |
  4. | a b c d e f g h                           d |
  5. | a b c d e f g h                           e |
  6. | a b c d e f g h                           f |
  7. | a b c d e f g h                           g |
  8. | a b c d e f g h                           h |
     +---------------------------------------------+
```

Without the quotation marks, Stata will try to make sense of `a` as a variable or scalar name, and bail out if that does not work. Even if that works, it will not be able to make sense of how you want to combine it with `b`, and will bail out then.

In short, you usually need " " to deal with literal strings. The `matrix *names` commands are special, because their inputs are necessarily literal strings (even when they are numeric characters).

Comment: Thank you, Nick. I was after the 3rd of your interpretations. I was not aware of the "world()" command.

Comment: OK, but it's `word()` not `world()` and it's a function, not a command.